# How to clear status before validation on Formik submit?

Tags: reactjs, formik

I'm using Formik with yup validation, following this pattern:

```js
const handleSubmit = async (values, { setStatus }) => {
  setStatus(''); // clean errors messages
  try {
    ... do submit work ...
      const res = await sendData( convertValues(values)); //
    ... more work
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e);
    setStatus('an error occurred '...);
  }
};

const validationSchema = Yup.object({
  code: Yup.string().required(t('Required')),
  ....
});

return (
    <Formik onSubmit={handleSubmit} initialValues={initialValues} validationSchema={validationSchema}>
      {({ setFieldValue, status }) => (
        <Form>
          ....
          <MyErrorComponent msg={status} />
        </Form>
      )}
    </Formik>
);
```

This has problems in this scenario:

1. User submits forms. Validation passes ok, but some error occurs inside `handleSubmit`. An error message is shown in status
2. User edits form and retries
3. This time a validation error occurs
4. The validation error is displayed inside the input field...but the old status messsage is not cleared.

This happens because validation occurs before submit, hence `setStatus('')` is not called.
What's the recommended way to deal with this?

Comment: Is there a reason why you are passing setStatus as an argument when you handle submit, can we see that component

Comment: IMO, I think leaving the status with the old one has better UX than to clear it. In most cases, an error that occurs on the onSubmit is usually a bug, a failure in logic, or the form got rejected from the backend (mostly technical stuff and the user, who might not have any technical knowledge may not know what to do). By leaving it there, the user can see why the form got rejected and go ahead and contact people in charge or refresh the page. So I don't see any reason to reset the status.

Comment: @leonbloy If none of the answers solve your problem, you can update your question for the current problem situation.

Answer (score 1):

#### Option 1

You can add `validate` call in every form input so when ever user change input `status` message will be cleared.

```js
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { Formik, Form, Field, ErrorMessage } from "formik";
import * as Yup from "yup";

const schema = Yup.object().shape({
  name: Yup.string().required("Name"),
  age: Yup.number().required("Number").positive().integer()
});

const MyForm = () => (
  <div>
    <Formik
      initialValues={{ name: "", age: "" }}
      validationSchema={schema}
      onSubmit={(values, actions) => {
        console.log("submited", values);
        actions.setStatus("")
        try {
          throw new Error("Something went wrong")
        }
        catch (error) {
          actions.setStatus(error.message);
        }
      }}
      render={({
        status,
        isSubmitting,
        setStatus,
        dirty,
        values,
        handleReset,
        errors,
        touched
      }) => {
        const field_props_with_validation = function() {
          const name = arguments[0];
          const type = arguments[1] || "text";
          const placeholder = arguments[2] || "";
          return {
            name,
            type,
            placeholder,
            validate: () => {
              setStatus("");
            }
          }
        }

        return (
          <Form>
            {status}
            {["name", "age"].map((field, key) => (
              <div key={key}>
                <Field {...field_props_with_validation(field)} />
                <ErrorMessage name={field} component="div" />
              </div>
            ))}
            <button type="submit">Enter</button>
          </Form>
        );
      }}
    />
  </div>
);

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Registration Form</h1>
      <MyForm />
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

#### Option 2

`validation` can be `disabled` on form input change using `validateOnChange` props and only `validate` when user submits the form.

**Note:** In this case you would have to handle the validation, status will not be cleared until user resubmits the form.

```js
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { Formik, Form, Field, ErrorMessage } from "formik";
import * as Yup from "yup";

const schema = Yup.object().shape({
  name: Yup.string().required("Name"),
  age: Yup.number().required("Number").positive().integer()
});

const MyForm = () => (
  <div>
    <Formik
      initialValues={{ name: "", age: "" }}
      validateOnChange={false}
      onSubmit={async (values, actions) => {
        actions.setStatus("");
        await schema.validate(values, {
          abortEarly: false // not to stop on single validation fail
                            // and return single error message
        })
        .then(() => {
          try {
            throw new Error("Some error")
          }
          catch (error) {
            actions.setStatus(error.message);
          }
        })
        .catch(err => {
          let errors = {};
          Object.keys(values).forEach((key, idx) => {
            if (err && err.errors && err.errors[idx]) {
              errors[key] = err.errors[idx];
            }
          });

          actions.setErrors(errors)
        })
      }}
      render={({
        status,
        isSubmitting,
        dirty,
        values,
        handleReset,
        errors,
        touched
      }) => {
        return (
          <Form>
            {status}
            {["name", "age"].map((field, key) => (
              <div key={key}>
                <Field name={field} type="text" placeholder={field} />
                <ErrorMessage name={field} component="div" />
              </div>
            ))}
            <button type="submit">Enter</button>
          </Form>
        );
      }}
    />
  </div>
);

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Registration Form</h1>
      <MyForm />
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think u should use something like this:

```
<Formik
      initialValues={
        firstName: '',
        email: ''
      }
      validationSchema={
        Yup.object().shape({
          email: Yup.string()
            .email("Must be a valid email")
            .max(255)
            .required("Email is required"),
          firstname: Yup.string()
            .max(255)
            .required("First name is required"),
        })
      }
      onSubmit={(e, { resetForm }) => {
        let val = e;
        postSubmit (e.firstName,e.email);
        // ur rest logic
        // resetForm({
        //  values: {
        //    ...e,
        //  },
        });
      }}
    >
      {({ handleChange, values, initialValues, errors }) => (
        // Your form jsx
      )}
</Formik>
```

Don't use `useState` with formik, let Formik take care of error and validation!

I did use this pattern and it works perfectly.

If you didn't find the way, share your form ill make it for you!

Answer (score 0):

It has a validation process on onMouseDown event. You can avoid duplicate validation by prevent default on Submit button.

```
 onMouseDown={(event: any): void => {
                event.preventDefault();
              }}
```

after that Formik automatically clear status

Answer (score 0):

you can use hooks for formik `useFormik`

```js
import { useFormik } from 'formik';
....
const formik = useFormik({
   initialValues: {},
   validationSchema={validationSchema}
   onSubmit: values => {
     handleSubmit(values);
   },
 });

const handleSubmit = async (values, { setStatus }) => {
  try {
    ... do submit work ...
    const res = await sendData( convertValues(values)); //
    ... more work
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e);
    //change statuvalues or display errors
    //formik.setValue...
    //formik.setError...
  }
};

 
 return (
   <form onSubmit={formik.handleSubmit}>
     ....
     <button type="submit">Submit</button>
   </form>
 );
```

Answer (score 0):

Personally I think that status is only to notify user. So I would notify them from a snackbar / notification by telling them there is an error. Then I would remove them if there's an error on the validation form so they would focus on fixing the wrong one

Here's an example code and [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/bold-sound-sq1cz?file=/src/App.js):

```
const validationSchema = yup.object().shape({
  name: yup.string().required("Required")
});

const initialValues = {
  name: "John Doe"
};

export const FormikTextField = ({ className, ...props }) => {
  const [field, meta] = useField(props);
  const { setStatus } = useFormikContext();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (meta.error) {
      setStatus("");
    }
  }, [meta.error]);

  return (
    <>
      <TextField
        variant="outlined"
        {...field}
        {...props}
        FormHelperTextProps={{ error: true }}
        helperText={meta.error && meta.touched ? String(meta.error) : null}
        aria-invalid={Boolean(meta.error)}
      />
    </>
  );
};

export default function App() {
  const handleSubmit = (values, { setStatus }) => {
    setStatus("status set!");
  };

  return (
    <Formik
      enableReinitialize
      initialValues={initialValues}
      validationSchema={validationSchema}
      onSubmit={handleSubmit}
    >
      {(props) => (
        <Form>
          {props.status && <p>{props.status}</p>}
          <div className="App">
            <FormikTextField name="name" variant="outlined" label="Name" />
            <Button type="submit" variant="contained">
              Submit
            </Button>
          </div>
        </Form>
      )}
    </Formik>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your assumption is correct. Form validation done before submission. What you have to do is, add this errors clearing step in a custom validate function as

```
const validate = values =>
  {
   // If you want some other custom validations, you can do that on values parameter
   setStatus('');
  };

const handleSubmit = async (values, { setStatus }) => {
//  setStatus(''); // clean errors messages
  try {
    ... do submit work ...
      const res = await sendData( convertValues(values)); //
    ... more work
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e);
    setStatus('an error occurred '...);
  }
};

const validationSchema = Yup.object({
  code: Yup.string().required(t('Required')),
  ....
});

return (
    <Formik onSubmit={handleSubmit} initialValues={initialValues} validationSchema={validationSchema}
validate={validate}>
      {({ setFieldValue, status }) => (
        <Form>
          ....
          <MyErrorComponent msg={status} />
        </Form>
      )}
    </Formik>
);
```

For more details, check this [CombinedValidations](https://github.com/formium/formik/blob/master/examples/CombinedValidations.js) example.

As you are using Async form submission as illustrated in [async-submission](https://codesandbox.io/s/github/jaredpalmer/formik/tree/master/examples/async-submission?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark). You might have to either use async validation function by creating a wrapper Promise like [this](https://github.com/formium/formik/blob/master/examples/AsyncValidation.js) or make you form submission sync.

**Above examples' links are from [official docs](https://formik.org/docs/examples/more-examples).**